# Those/this kind of thing

Tags: colloquial-language

I was asked about whether I'd like to go on a vacation or stay home and relax. While answering it I said:

"I prefer staying home and relaxing. I like to have a cup of coffee, take a hot shower. **Those/this** kind of thing."

For some reason 'those' sounds better to me here. Which one's more natural between 'those' and 'these' here?

Answer (score 1):

"those" wopuld be used with a plural. "Those kinds of things" but "This kind of thing".  I would say that "those kind of thing" is incorrect. It is certainly not natural.

Comment: In my context which one's more natural between  'these kinds of things' and 'those kinds of things?'